# WCF Service with entity framework - error if foreign key

Tags: c#, wcf, frameworks, foreign-keys, entity

I have a problem. Note that I am a beginner and that the answer could be simple...

I Use Visual Studio 2012 and I want to create a WCF Service with Entity Framework to get access to a database. It can be done in 5-10 minutes...

- I created a simple database with SQL Express (For example : 2 tables : Client and City, with idCity as a foreign key in the Client table)
- I created a new WCF service
- I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (.edmx) linked to my database
- I created a method to return all my clients

When I try the method in the WCF Test Client or in a console application, I get a CommunicazionException error.

But it works correctly if I remove the foreign key in my Client table...

My getClients method :

```
public Client[] GetClients()
{
    using (ClientEntities context = new ClientEntities ())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return context.Client.ToArray();
    }

}
```

I used the default configuration...

Is the a special way to do it ? (My code is certainly incomplete to do what I want)

In my application, I want to get all the clients and for each of them, display the client name and the city name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly what your problem is without more details, but the fact that it works when you remove the foreign key on the client table leads me to believe you have a database or Entity Framework issue.

You might want to try updating your .edmx.
Right click on .edmx diagram and select update model from database and select you two tables.

If that does not work you can also can try deleting each of the table from the models (right click on the edxml viewer and select delete) and then re-adding them using the update model from database as well.

If you are still having issues try to figure out exactly where your code is throwing the exception. Debug the GetClient method and put a breakpoint right after the return statement to see if the error is occurring when your query is being executed. If that is the case you should get a more detailed exception message to assist in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried to do this kind of changes a lot of times but I still get the error. I also tried to use an other database from the web without success... The error should come from the method (like using ".Include("City") " or a thing like that ) or from the web.config, but I didn't change anything in it...

Comment: Ok I maybe manage to resolve the problem : My classes were generated in the file "Model.cs" and in my client class, I removed the "virtual" keyword from "public virtual city city{ get; set; }" I don't know if I will have other problems, but It works for now. But I still don't know how to get the city name instead of the id in my application

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 public Client[] GetClients()
  {
     using (ClientEntities context = new ClientEntities ())
       {
          context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
          context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
          return context.Client.ToArray();
        }

  }
```